# Wordpress login redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am trying to log into a wordpress site (hosted with 1&1), but when clicking "Anmelden" it only reloads the page (using an invalid login still displays an error message and the site still works).
I have tried clearing cache and cookies, opening the site on a different pc, renaming the plugins folder, renaming the folder of the currently active theme and deleting the .htaccess file.

I also noticed that in the database, the row `option_id` of the table `wp_options` contains 28 NULL entries, which seems weird to me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running wordpress 5.6 (db_version 49752) with PhP 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the ID field of the table wp_usermeta was somehow not set to autoincrement resulting in a corrupted database after the update to wordpress 5.6. Assigning ids to the NULL fields and setting the field to autoincrement resolved the issue.